# Глобальная переменная с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как реализовать следующее. Есть примерно 8 пар `.h` и `.cpp` файлов, в одном из них есть функция, которая считывает введённые данные. Мне надо запомнить эти данные, чтобы я мог в остальных файлах ими пользоваться. Как это реализовать? В интернете что-то нашел про `extern`, но так и не получилось ничего.

Answer (score 8):

Везде, где собираетесь использовать глобальную переменную, включите её декларацию (declaration), например, пусть она будет в каком-то общем хедере. А только в одном из модулей cpp определите эту переменную (definition)

File 1:

```
int GlobalVariable;         // определение в одном файле. здесь переменная "будет жить"
void SomeFunction();
void AnotherFunction();
int main() {
    GlobalVariable = 1;
    SomeFunction();
    AnotherFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

File 2:

```
extern int GlobalVariable;  // декларация во всех пользующихся файлах
void SomeFunction() {
    ++GlobalVariable;
}
```

File 3:

```
extern int GlobalVariable;  // декларация во всех пользующихся файлах
void AnotherFunction() { 
    --GlobalVariable;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо все заработало! А если мне так надо создать еще и тип char, то я в главном файле делаю так: char* ci[size], а уже во всех других так: extern char* ci[size]. Это правельно? ведь сам массив я не могу передовать значит просто выделяю место и создаю указатель?

Comment: Смотря что хотите получить. char* ci[size] - это будет массив на size элементов указателей на строки. Если же хотите работать со строкой, то нужно char ci[size]. Да, в других модулях нужно будет написать extern char* ci[size] или extern char ci[size] соответственно. Касательно передачи массива напоминаю, что имя массива - указатель на начало массива.

Comment: Мне нужно работать со строкой. Если я объявляю в клавном файле вот так:  char cI[BUF_SIZE]; то программа не компилируется и выдает следующую ошибку: globVars.obj : error LNK2005: "char * cI" (?cI@@3PADA) already defined in Diplom.obj объявляю в другом файле переменную следующим образом(extern char cI[BUF_SIZE]; и пробывал так еще extern char* cI[BUF_SIZE];), но если я в главном файле делаю так: char* cI[BUF_SIZE]; то все компилируется, но как я понял это будет не то что мне надо. :( подскажите что не так?

Comment: все решилось спасибо, сам затупил.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще ИМХО, раз уж задачка решается на C++, то лучше сразу проектировать правильно, ибо глобальные переменные - всё-таки зло. ;)
А именно сделать следующее:

1. В одном исходнике создать класс, который управляет всем - Manager;
2. В другом реализовать класс, который считывает данные и хранит их - DataReader;
3. В остальных - прочую логику работы, которая реализует всё, что вам нужно.

Правильная архитектура решит множество проблем.
Пример:

file "data_reader.h"

```
struct MyData 
{
    // ... мои данные ...
    int my_field;
};

class DataReader {
    MyData my_data;
public:
    bool ReadData( const std::string& data_file )
    {
        // ... считываем входные данные в my_data ...
        return true;
    }
    // по требованию использующей стороны отдаём данные
    TMyData& Data()
    {
        return my_data;
    }
};
```

file "manager.h"

```
 #include "data_reader.h"
 #include "mylogic1.h"
 #include "mylogic2.h"
 // ...
 #include "mylogic8.h"
 #include <string>
class Manager {
    DataReader data_reader;
    MyLogic1   my_logic1;
    MyLogic1   my_logic2;
    // ...
    MyLogic1   my_logic8;
    bool       init_ok;
public:
    // В конструкторе менеджера сказать всем классам, реализующим мою логику, 
    // откуда брать прочитанные данные
    Manager(const std::string& data_file)
        : my_logic1 (data_reader)
        , my_logic2 (data_reader)
        // ...
        , my_logic8 (data_reader)
    {
        init_ok = data_reader.ReadData(data_file);
    }
    //
    bool IsInitOk() 
    {
        return init_ok;
    }
    //
    void Work()
    {
        my_logic1.Work();
        my_logic2.Work();
        // ...
        my_logic8.Work();
    }
};
```

Реализация моей логики "mylogic1.h"

```
#include "data_reader.h"
class MyLogic1 {
    DataReader& dr;
public:
    MyLogic1( TDataReader& data_reader )
        : dr (data_reader)
    {}
    //
    void Work()
    {
        // ... моя логи работы; когда мне нужны считанные данные, делаю вот так:
        printf("Readen data: %dn", dr.Data().my_field);
        // (!) Так нам не нужно будет использовать никаких глобальных переменных ...
    }
};
```

files mylogic2.h ... mylogic8.h

```
// Прочие файлы, с реализацией моей логики; они также используют DataReader::Data(), 
// чтобы получить доступ к считанным данным.
```

file "main.cpp"

```
#include "manager.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Инициализируем менеджер
    Manager manager("my.dat");
    // Если инициализация прошла успешно, работаем
    if (manager.IsInitOk()) {
        manager.Work();
        return 0;
    }
    // Ошибка
    return 1;
}
```

Преимуществ реализации без глобальных переменных множество. Главные из них такие:

- Не будет путаницы имён переменных, когда вы будете разрабатывать сложную программу;
- Вы сами можете выбрать, где вам хранить ВСЕ данные "скопом" (экземпляр класса Manager): на стеке, на куче или вообще сделать её глобальной;
- Можно создать множество менеджеров (в зависимости от задачи) и манипулировать ими, как угодно;
- и многое другое... :)

Ну + предлагаю вообще почитать про паттерны проектирования C++, ибо то, что я здесь наваял - это их "велосипедная" смесь. :)