# Передать некоторые данные функции, находящейся в отдельном хедер-файле

Tags: c++builder, сокет, c++, winsock

На самом деле, давно озадачился и сейчас уже мозг себе поломал - поэтому туго соображаю и прошу помощи.
Есть проект один. Допустим, в Unit1.cpp. Создал отдельно header-файл sendrec.h, в который записал функцию отправки команды на сервер. Функция должна запускаться по таймеру раз в секунду:

```
#ifndef sendrecH
#define sendrecH

void sendCMD()
{
    WSADATA wsd;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsd)!=0)
    {
       ShowMessage("Ошибка старта сокета");
    }
    else   
    {        
       SOCKET S;
       struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
       S=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
       servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
       servaddr.sin_port=htons(SERVPORT);
       servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(SERVIP); 

       char *buf = "\xff\xff\xff\xff getstatus";
       sendto(S,buf,strlen(buf),0,(SOCKADDR *) & servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
       }
}

#endif
```

**Вопрос #1**: Как этой функции передать из Unit1.cpp SERVPORT и SERVIP? Пробовал через глобальные переменные, но не получилось что-то. Если прямо тут в функции написать ip и порт, то всё работает без проблем.
**Вопрос #2**: Будет еще одна функция такая же, но в скобках будет дописана команда sendCMD(char * command). Собственно, насколько это грамотно/неграмотно хранить такие вот функции, немаленькие даже, в header-файле? Пробовал делать cpp-шку с таким же названием, в хедер-файле указал заголовки функций, но компилятор написал что-то типа "функции пустые". А так не ругается ни на что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Собственно - насколько это грамотно/неграмотно хранить такие вот функции, не маленькие даже, в header-файле?

Полный ацццтой. Ситуация такая, что код должен храниться в C/CPP-файлах, т.к. именно они компилируются. Если Вы описываете ф-цию в одном файле, а подключаете к остальным через h-ник, в котором ее заголовок, то физически она одна и просто вызывается между разными модулями. А если функция полностью описана в h-нике, то она, получается, будет продублирована в каждом c/cpp-файле, где этот h-ник включается. Нехорошо.

Но есть исключения: в инклюд-файлы разумно вставлять встраиваемые ф-ции (inline), т.к. они развертываются по месту вызова и в этот момент нужно знать, что представляет собой тело ф-ции. Еще шаблоны в h-никах должны быть целиком. Т.к. они тоже разворачиваются по месту применения. А вот для обычных классов - в h-нике только объявление, т.е. по сути интерфейс. А сам код - в c/cpp-файлах. На самом деле на практике это все очень хорошо чувствуется.

> Вопрос #1: как этой функции передать из Unit1.cpp SERVPORT и SERVIP? Пробовал через глобальные переменные, но не получилось что-то. Если прямо тут в функции написать ip и порт, то всё работает без проблем.

Действительно, вариантов два. Или передавать такие данные как аргументы ф-ции (при этом необходимо изменить ее прототип). Или оставить как глобальные, но при этом тогда нужно разобраться с областями <s>определений</s> видимости. Т.е. в том модуле, где располагается тело ф-ции эти переменные должны быть объявлены.

Comment: Вариант первый отпадает, т.к. char-команд, которые будут передаваться в sendCMD (char *command) в разных функциях много, и постоянно приписывать сервер и порт не катит, к тому же, это значит, что так и так придется делать глобальные переменные, что бы во всех функциях нажатий кнопок и т.д. передавался адрес и порт сервера командой в функцию.  
Вариант второй - его я и реализовал, но есть НО:  
Во-первых, я пока не переделывал .h с функцией, что в начале вопроса у меня, во-вторых - все говорят, что глобальные переменные злейшее зло

Comment: и вот по второму у меня вопрос - иначе в функцию отправки сообщения на сервер никак не передать ip и port?  
Я вот пока ещё мало соображаю по части структур и классов, и снова вопрос - если я в sendrec.h создам класс, туда помещу заголовки функций, функции солью в sendrec.cpp файл, можно ли будет без глобальных переменных (ну, скажем так, открытых, тех, что extern) как-то между модулями "общаться"?

Comment: Сейчас последний коммент отсюда: http://hashcode.ru/questions/9716/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#9718 осмысливаю и пытаюсь понять, как себе это можно прикрутить. Если можно.

Comment: Предположим, что у нас все ф-ции работы с сервером лежат в отдельном c/cpp-файле. В нем есть глобальные для этого файла переменные SERVPORT и SERVIP. Никто не мешает сделать доступными ф-ции установки значений этих переменных из других модулей. Минусы - очень легко нарушить логику программы, забыв обновить SERVPORT/SERVIP перед последующим вызовом ф-ции.<p>
Если же сделать глобальную переменную extern, т.е. доступной из всех модулей, где она объявлена с этим ключевым словом, то по сути получается то же самое. Но при этом Вы теряете контроль над установкой значений.

Comment: Потому что вызов ф-ции переделать проще. На него проще поставить точку останова, сделать вывод диагностических сообщений (в тот же поток stderr), ну, и т.д. Да и использование глобальных переменных не хорошо само по себе. <p>
На самом деле, коли пишете на C++, то было бы, наверное, грамотнее все запихать в класс. Причем при создании экземпляра класса - указываете IP/порт, а далее работаете с ним. При необходимости подключиться к другому серверу - например, грохаете текущий экземпляр, создаете новый. При этом функции-члены вполне естественно имеют доступ к переменным класса.

Comment: Спасибо.  
<<Причем при создании экземпляра класса - указываете IP/порт, а далее работаете с ним. При необходимости подключиться к другому серверу - например, грохаете текущий экземпляр, создаете новый.>> Можно немножко подробней? самую малость:)

Comment: Пример: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization
Т.е. когда создаем объект класса типа файл, мы передаем конструктору имя файла. Далее как только файл перестает быть нужен - объект грохается. В примере - в случае выхода за пределы блока фигурных скобок, где объект объявлен. Соответственно, в классе файла никто не мешает сделать ф-цию reopen, которая будет текущие данные сбрасывать, затем старый файл закрывать и под видом старого объекта открывать новый файл.
Второй вариант (а-ля MFC): объявляем объект класса, инициализируем его вызовом спец. ф-ции члена, работаем.

Answer (score 1):

№1. Почему бы не передавать всё как параметры функции?

№2. [У Бьерна Страуструпа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_C%2B%2B) описан порядок организации файлов ([здесь](http://lib.ru/CPPHB/cpptut.txt) текст книги, например, можно почитать разделы  "1.3.6 Модули", "4.3.2 Множественные заголовочные файлы"). Какая-то часть программы выделена в отдельный модуль - замечательно, объявления функций выносим в заголовочный файл, реализацию функций - в `cpp`. Там, где используем функции, инклюдим заголовок. Почему у Вас не получилось - неясно, надо посмотреть код

А [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9716/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#9718) вопрос/ответ по поводу глобальных переменных.

Comment: По вопросу 1: я в функциях сам накосячил, по этому они не работали даже без глобальных переменных. Сейчас нашел косяк, подправил его тут в своём вопросе, завтра попробую, по идее глобальные переменные должны заработать. 
По второму: сам не знаю, почему у меня не получилось, но в принципе делал немного торопясь тогда, опять же, завтра сяду, поразбираюсь, может, найду, в чем проблема.
За ссылку на книгу спасибо, ознакомлюсь.

Comment: Вообще, при включении .h файла, содержащего функцию в несколько .c файлов gcc при линковке выдает ошибку  'multiple definition of ...'

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно функции в  **cpp** файле, прототипы в **.h**.
Параметры (host, port) или глобальные переменные или статические локальные, изменяемые вызовом вспомогательной функции ? - дело вкуса и совместимости с уже написанными программами.

И еще (м.б. важно) socket() (а также WSAStartup()) надо вызывать один раз ! (например при первом вызове) и запоминать результат в static переменной. Иначе (конечно без close()) дескрипторы OS скоро закончатся.